# WooCommerce how to check if page is_shop() in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**In WooCommerce**, My Category Listing page and product listing page are rendered from archieve-product.php ( By Default) . How to check if page **is_shop()** in **functions.php**? As is_shop function does not work in functions.php. I simply want to remove **my sidebar from Category listing** page not from product listing page.

Comment: What is your question? Using the function is fairly straight forward: *"Returns true when on the product archive page (shop)"*.

Comment: Yes .. But the problem is that When I click on particular category. The products are displayed of that categories which is also being rendered from the same archieve-product.php. So the side bar get dis appear even in product listing page.  ... Does this make any sense :/ ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a condition into  **"archive-product.php"** for category page like,

```
    $cate = get_queried_object();
    if(is_product_category()  && $cate->parent != 0 ){

         // Write code here
         //include sidebar here
    }
```

By using this code this will check the page for product_category and also check for a parent.

Answer (score 24):

When placed inside a hook, `is_shop` will work in functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );

function custom_template_redirect() {

    if( is_shop() ) :

         // code logic here

    endif;    
}
```

Here is a list of all [WooCommerce conditionals](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Thi sis should be accepted as the correct answer. This one worked for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

call it using WordPress Hook pre get posts

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','nameTheFunction');

function nameTheFunction(){

   if(is_shop()){

    // your code here 

  }

}// function end here
```

Read more about pre get posts Hook

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `function_exists`

```
if( function_exists("is_shop") ) {
    // call it or do something else
}
else {
    // load it from somewhere
}
```

Official docs: https://secure.php.net/function_exists

Comment: The function is "is_shop", so your check would be `function_exists('is_shop')`.

Comment: Cool thats working for me now :) Well but still I have a problem. My category listing page and product listing page are rendering from same page "archieve-product.php" . i just want to remove side bar from category listing page . can i do it from functions.php? Currently it got removed from both the pages with the above code.

Comment: @kdpatel you should post some code (perhaps in another question) that gives some more detail about what is wrong

Comment: `add_action('init', 'remove_sidebar_woo');
function remove_sidebar_woo(){


    if( function_exists("is_shop") ) {
        // call it or do something else
        remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
    }
    else {
        // load it from somewhere
    }

}
`

Comment: I think you want to call `is_shop()` . My function just determines whether or not it exists.  You really should edit the original post instead of posting the code in comments.